# Some Na values and not all

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

Assume that you have a dataset like starwars. Also assume that you have 2 columns one numeric with 20 NA values and the other with species (human,Droid,machine,etc).

How to convert using **pipes**, **only** the na values that belong to category humans to the mean of the heights?

If we convert it to the total it will be wrong as machines may be a lit smaller or higher and as a result we will have some strange values as for the height of the humans.

P.s. I know how to do it using replace or ifelse, but how to add the categorization

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to find out how to produce a reproducible example, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how to ask a good question on the site. It will help people help you.

Comment: something along the lines of `data %>% group_by(species) %>% mutate(heights = if_else(is.na(heights), mean(heights, na.rm = TRUE), heights))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the starwars scenario, you can do the following

```
library(dplyr)

starwars %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% 
  mutate(height = if_else(species == "Human" & is.na(height), mean(height, na.rm = TRUE), as.double(height))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

As you can see from here, `height` is filled with the average only with Human as species

```
library(dplyr)

starwars %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% 
  mutate(newheight = if_else(species == "Human" & is.na(height), mean(height, na.rm = TRUE), as.double(height))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(species, height, newheight) %>% 
  filter(is.na(height))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   species height newheight
#>   <chr>    <int>     <dbl>
#> 1 Human       NA      177.
#> 2 Human       NA      177.
#> 3 Human       NA      177.
#> 4 Human       NA      177.
#> 5 Droid       NA       NA 
#> 6 NA          NA       NA
```

In this specific example, you need to transform `height` into a `double` because it's an `integer`, and, since `if_else` is type-consistent and from the `mean` you receive a `double`, you need to transform `height` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I have not thought about doubles!!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to replace NAs by group means?

This should do:

```
data(starwars)

head(starwars)

#This shows one missing value (NAs) for "Droid"
starwars %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarize(M = mean(height, na.rm=T),
            NAs = sum(is.na(height)))

#Replace NAs by group-wise means
starwars <- starwars %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  mutate(height = if_else(is.na(height), mean(height, na.rm=T), as.double(height) )) %>%
  ungroup()

#Now no missing value any more and means (M) remains the same
starwars %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarize(M = mean(height, na.rm=T),
            NAs = sum(is.na(height)))
```